# Images in Angular5 are not getting loaded in HTML when using a network path for the image source

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular5

I am working on an e-commerce application. To load list of products i am consuming a rest api through which i am getting JSON data.

In the JSON data I am getting the network path of image. When the list of products is rendered in the html, the src of image is populated with the url, but image doesn't seems to be rendered in the html.

I'm using following tag to load the image

```
                                <img [src]="item.image" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

[I can image link in the browser but image is not loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dahpF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYjHg.png)

Comment: Did you check the network tab in the console for any errors?

Comment: Looks like more of a css issue rather than angular..

Comment: @ClydeLobo Yes, it says 403 (Forbidden) for the image url, however when I  us the url in browser the image comes out correctly.

Comment: It's your server not allowing the images to be loaded may be on another domain

Comment: @ClydeLobo I don't think it's the case because when i copy the url of image from the debugger and open it in a new tab, it just open up. And strangely next time that particular image comes up with angular also without any error. Seems like the image is getting cached. Please see the debugger image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dahpF.png

Comment: @ChandanSidana That's the inspect screen. I was referring to the networks tab. Also when you open the image in a new tab, the image is fetched from the same domain and not from another domain

Comment: @ClydeLobo Ok I agree with you that I am using the same domain to fetch the image which is working fine as expected. However, when i reload my application page after fetching the image in new tab, this particular image starts showing in the application also(may be due to cache). Then why this time it's not showing any error in my application network tab although the url of image is still of another domain?